# Printing the output of an if-then statement in another column

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

This sounds like the most simple thing ever but here I am.

I have a column with positive and negative numbers. I'm trying to script a code that will print either "P" or "N" in column B (or C or D, doesn't matter) depending on the value of the cell.

For example, if cell A2 has the value -32, then cell B2 should be assigned the string "N". Then goes A3/B3, A4/B4, and so on.

My trouble isn't with the if-then-else stament per se, rather HOW I can get the output to be printed where I want it to be.

```
Sub Negatives()
value = Range("A:A")
    If Sgn(value) < 0 Then
        //??? N
    ElseIf Sgn(value) >= 0 Then
        //??? P
    End If
End Sub
```

Should I be using a for-loop instead to iterate through every value in the column?

Comment: Do you need to do this with VBA? this could be done with a formula. And yes, you will need to check the value of each cell individually

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad yes, I was asked to create a macro using VBA for my coworkers... I thought to do it with a formula and record the macro, but my boss wants it to actually coded (for some reason...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer yes. You could construct an array and stamp it in all at once but that will still require a loop to make decisions on each cell value.

I'd suggest:

```
Sub Negatives()
    Dim numberRange As Range
    Set numberRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns("A")
    
    For Each cell In numberRange.Cells
    
        If cell.Value < 0 Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "N"
        ElseIf cell.Value >= 0 Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "P"
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The offset function makes so much sense here. Cheers!